# How do I get the this keyword working in a object literal I created?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been having problems with the **this** keyword, and though I have read a number of posts and articles about using **this** in a object literal it is not working in the way people are explaining it. I have an object called **me** and it has a number of properties, and I also have method called **bio** that will list the properties in text and it will be added to a variable called **message** which ultimately will be inserted into a div with the id of **summary**. The bio method uses a lot of **this** keywords in the text,and when I try to activate **me.bio**, I get error messages. I know that if I replace the keyword **this** for **me** it run normally. But, I really need to know how to use the **this** keyword correctly when making object literals. Here is my code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c51hdod7/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="ex1">
    <h2>Ajax and Objects</h2>
    <p>
     I created an object about myself and added around 12 or so properties about me and two methods about myself as well
    </p>


    <h4>The Buttons of My Life:</h4>
    <button id="life">My Normal Life</button>
    <button id="ajaxLife">My Life Now... with AJAX</button>


</div>

<div id="summary"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var me = {

fName: 'George',
lName: 'Walsh',
job: { name: 'Retail Clerk', pay: 9.50, company:'Harbor Freight Tools', enjoyJob:false},
age: 26,
height: '6\'0',
happiness: 48,
happyState : function()
            {
              if(me.happiness > 75)
              {
                return 'happier than I have ever been';
              }
              else if (me.happiness < 75 && me.happiness > 50)
              {
                return 'fairly satisfied with my life}';

              }
              else if (me.happiness < 50 && me.happiness > 25)
              {
                return 'not in a good place with my life';
              }
              else{

                return 'thinking about killing myself';

              }
            } 
,
virgin: true,
weight: 230,
bio : function()
    {
      var message;
      var m;
       message = '<p>Hello, my name is '+this.fName+' '+this.lName+'</p>';
       message += '<p> I am '+this.age+' years old</p>';
        m = (this.job.enjoyJob == true)? 'awesome': 'shitty';
       message += '<p> And I work at a '+ m +' job called '+this.job.company+' and\
                   I only get paid '+this.job.pay+' an hour and my position is a '+this.job.name+'</p>';
        m =(this.virgin == true)? 'I have not dipped my penis in the soft walls of a vagina':'I am not a virgin anymore and I\'m fucking like crazy';
       message += '<p> I am currently '+this.happyState()+' and '+ m +'   </p>';
       message += '<p> I also weigh '+this.weight+' </p>';

      document.querySelector('div#summary').innerHTML = message;


    }



}


document.querySelector('button#life').onclick = me.bio;

document.querySelector('button#ajaxLife').onclick = loadAjax;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article provides a very good explanation about this and closure. 
http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Having a good understanding of "call", 'apply', 'bind' will also help.
http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

```js
var me = {

fName: 'George',
lName: 'Walsh',
job: { name: 'Retail Clerk', pay: 9.50, company:'Harbor Freight Tools', enjoyJob:false},
age: 26,
height: '6\'0',
happiness: 48,
happyState : function()
   {
     if(this.happiness > 75)
     {
       return 'happier than I have ever been';
     }
     else if (this.happiness < 75 && this.happiness > 50)
     {
    return 'fairly satisfied with my life}';
     
     }
     else if (this.happiness < 50 && this.happiness > 25)
     {
    return 'not in a good place with my life';
     }
     else{
     
    return 'thinking about killing myself';
     
     }
   } 
,
virgin: true,
weight: 230,
bio : function()
    {
   var message;
   var m;
    message = '<p>Hello, my name is '+this.fName+' '+this.lName+'</p>';
    message += '<p> I am '+this.age+' years old</p>';
     m = (this.job.enjoyJob == true)? 'awesome': 'shitty';
    message += '<p> And I work at a '+ m +' job called '+this.job.company+' and\ I only get paid '+this.job.pay+' an hour and my position is a '+this.job.name+'</p>';
  m =(this.virgin == true)? 'I have not dipped my penis in the soft walls of a vagina':'I am not a virgin anymore and I\'m fucking like crazy';
    message += '<p> I am currently '+this.happyState()+' and '+ m +'   </p>';
    message += '<p> I also weigh '+this.weight+' </p>';
   
   document.querySelector('div#summary').innerHTML = message;
 }



}


document.querySelector('button#life').onclick = me.bio.bind(me);

// document.querySelector('button#ajaxLife').onclick = loadAjax;
```

Comment: Yeah, Kelvin, that isn't right.  He doesn't want to set the onclick property of the button to the return value of `bio()` -- he wants `bio` invoked when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You have run into a common confusion.  It seems sensible that in the following case:

```
var p = {
  a : 1,
  m : function() { return this.a }
}
var f = p.m
f()
```

that the function call `f()` would return 1 but, nope, it won't.  `this` is bound at the point the function is called, and when you call `f()`, `this` is the global context and `this.a` is probably undefined.

Consider:

```
var p = {
  a : 1,
  m : function() { return this.a }
}
var q = {
  a : 2,
  m : p.m
}
q.m()
```

Here, `q.m()` will return 2.

Your solution, using a named variable instead `this`, is as good as any, but QoP proposes another.

And if your references to your emotional state are joking, you should probably learn to make better jokes; if not, you might seek professional help.

**Edit**

QoP deleted his answer for no reason I can see, but it looked like this:

```
document.querySelector('button#life').onclick = me.bio.bind(me);
```

`bind` is exactly suited to your purpose, but it only became available with ECMA-262 5th edition (2009), so really old, creaky hooptie browsers won't support it.  Consider using [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Reuben proposed doing the binding manually, which is also good.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the context that the function is being called from.

Because your `me.bio` is being called when the button is being clicked and is being stored in the button's `onclick` property then `this` is actually the button and not the object `me`.

If you wish to make `this` the object `me` then you need to use the call function.

Replace

`document.querySelector('button#life').onclick = me.bio;`

with

`document.querySelector('button#life').onclick = function(){me.bio.call(me)};`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: maybe you can use "me.bio.bind(me)" instead.

Comment: True, bind would be a more niche solution.

Comment: Just an addition though as @Malvolio pointed out, bind wont work on older browsers. Call has been supported since 1st edition (ECMA-262) so it depends on what browsers are being targeted by the developer.